# OIDC - Single-Sign-On with multiple Identity Providers

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, owin

We have in my organization an existing ASP.NET web application built in a SAAS model that our customers (users from different organizations) login through username/password authentication method. Users' credentials are hashed and stored in our database. We are currently working on adding a SSO feature to our application that would allow end-users from certain organizations to login with SSO using their own Identity Provider (Azure AD, Google, Okta, etc.) to perform the user authentication. We are using the OpenId Connect protocol to establish the SSO connection with IdP, and more specifically the Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN) middleware. We have implemented the following:

1. Our SAAS application offers customers the ability to opt for SSO authentication through a setting. End-users from these organizations will be authenticating to our application via SSO AND using their own IdP
2. Our application supports SSO connection from different IdPs (Azure AD, Google, Okta, etc.)
3. Our application stores SSO connection settings for each customer that opt for SSO authentication (Client Id, Authority, Secret, etc.). All these settings are configurable in our application, they're available upon registration of the application on IdP side.

My question is about the app registration. I know that in order for our application to communicate with IdP and initiate SSO authentication it needs to be registered on related IdP, so that it can create a trust relationship. I am wondering which party should be responsible of the app registration:

1. My organization owner of the SAAS application? or
2. Our customers willing to use SSO authentication method?

With option 1, my organization will have to have an "account" on each of the IdPs our customers use for authentication (I feel this is not ideal for us), register our application and have a mechanism to invite our customers IdP to connect to the registered app.
I feel like option 2 would be the best approach for us as we won't have to deal with app registration, as customers will be responsible of registering the application on their own IdP. From my organization end we will just need to deal with SSO connection settings (Client Id, and other...) which will be provided to us by our customers upon app registration. I wanted to check if this is a common situation that some have already experienced, and what would be the best/recommended approach to go with. Thanks.

I am expecting app registration to be performed on customers side.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually recommend that your internal services and APIs only need to trust tokens from one Identity Provider, and in your case you have one openid connect provider inhouse. That then supports your users to authenticate to and optionally authenticate using an external provider, like how the image below tries to show:

[image]

In my experience, having your applications trust and handle tokens from multiple sources will be a pain, as many of the external tokens might look slightly different.